# Неочевидная утечка памяти

Tags: c++, linux, valgrind

Есть два сервера с идентичным ПО, железом и рабочим окружением. ОС старый добрый 6 дебиан. Разница лишь в количестве оперативки: 4 гига на тестовом и 128 на рабочем.
Есть код на C++, который обрабатывает сетевые соединения, получает данные и пишет их в базу. При выполнении идентичного запроса на тестовом сервере использование оперативки и виртуальной памяти держится на одном уровне, а на рабочем только растет.
Утечек памяти valgrind не нашел, структуры чисты, руками очищается даже выделяемая "лишняя" память векторов, плюс руками же чистится куча. 
Собственно вопрос: в какую сторону еще можно копнуть, чтобы разрешить проблему?

`ps ef -o vsize,rss,%mem -p pidof непалюсь`

Тестовый сервер

```
VSZ    RSS   %MEM 
448768 40832 0.6
```

Рабочий сервер

```
VSZ      RSS      %MEM
38446720 23682724 17.9
```

Comment: Какая конкретно метрика растет? VMEM?

Comment: @gbg растет и обычная, и виртуальная. Но только на рабочем.

Comment: Какие-нить конкретные статы `ps`'а добавь, что бы исключить банальное [недопонимание новичка](http://linuxatemyram.ru/)...

Answer (score 3):

Для поиска неявных утечек можно воспользоваться другим инструментом valgrind'а: [`massif`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html). Это профайлер кучи, который работает по следующему принципу: во время выполнения программы логируются все выделения/освобождения памяти, а также периодически делаются снимки использования памяти. В некоторых «детализированных» снимках сохраняется подробная статистика, сколько в каждой «точке аллокации» (функции в бектрейсе к malloc'у) было выделено, но не освобождено памяти. Логируются только точки аллокации, выделенная память из кучи к которым превосходит некий порог (по умолчанию ≥1% от общего объёма выделенного из кучи).

### Тестовый пример

Пара контейнеров, которые равномерно заполняются и освобождаются, но в Стеке элемент «Забыли» извлечь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

#include <cstdlib>

class Container {
public:
    virtual void store(int s) = 0;
    virtual int unstore() = 0;
    virtual ~Container() {};
};

class Stack: public Container { 
    std::stack<int> data;
public:
    virtual void store(int s) { data.push(s); }
    virtual int unstore() { 
        if (data.size() !=0 ) {
            auto rv = data.top();
//            data.pop();
            return rv;
        } else {
            return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Stack() {};
};

class Queue: public Container { 
    std::queue<int> data;
public:
    virtual void store(int s) { data.push(s); }
    virtual int unstore() { 
        if (data.size() !=0 ) {
            auto rv = data.front();
            data.pop();
            return rv;
        } else {
            return std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
        }
    }
    virtual ~Queue() {};
};

int main(void) {
    std::unique_ptr<Container> cont1 (new Stack);
    std::unique_ptr<Container> cont2 (new Queue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024*1024; ++i) {
        int num = rand();
        if (num<RAND_MAX/4) {
            cont1->store(num);
        } else if (num<RAND_MAX/4*2) {
            cont1->unstore();
        } else if (num<RAND_MAX/4*3) {
            cont2->store(num);
        } else {
            cont2->unstore();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

После запуска `valgrind --tool=massif ./mem_eater` получаем `massif.out.28861`.

Далее просматриваем его с помощью родной утилитки (к сожалению, сторонних графических инструментов для этого пока нет) `ms_print massif.out.28861` и получаем здоровенную простынку с текстом (оставлена только одна секция для наглядности):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./mem_eater
Massif arguments:   (none)
ms_print arguments: massif.out.28861
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    MB
1.116^                                                                       #
     |                                                                    @@@#
     |                                                                @@@@@@@#
     |                                                            @:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                                          @:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                                      ::::@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                                 @@@:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                             @@@@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                          :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                      @:@@:@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                                  ::::@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                               :@@:: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                          ::@:::@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                       :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |                  :::@@:@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |              ::::: :@ :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |           @@:: ::: :@ :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |       :::@@ :: ::: :@ :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     |   ::::: :@@ :: ::: :@ :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
     | :@: ::: :@@ :: ::: :@ :@:: @: :@ :: :@:@ :@@@ @@@ @:::: :@:@:@@@@@@@@@#
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Mi
     0                                                                   302.7

Number of snapshots: 64
 Detailed snapshots: [2, 8, 9, 16, 17, 19, 22, 25, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46, 48, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63 (peak)]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0              0                0                0             0            0
  1      5,073,918           83,184           82,976           208            0

 .....

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 40    224,967,222          841,304          829,744        11,560            0
98.63% (829,744B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->87.51% (736,256B) 0x10AB96: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->87.51% (736,256B) 0x10A919: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->87.51% (736,256B) 0x10A398: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_node() (stl_deque.h:600)
|     ->87.45% (735,744B) 0x109D4C: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:471)
|     | ->87.45% (735,744B) 0x109875: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |   ->87.03% (732,160B) 0x109499: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_stack.h:219)
|     |   | ->87.03% (732,160B) 0x10912E: Stack::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:19)
|     |   |   ->87.03% (732,160B) 0x108F11: main (mem_eater.cpp:55)
|     |   |     
|     |   ->00.43% (3,584B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     |   
|     ->00.06% (512B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->08.64% (72,704B) 0x4EC16EE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
| ->08.64% (72,704B) 0x400F448: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|   ->08.64% (72,704B) 0x400F559: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|     ->08.64% (72,704B) 0x4000B88: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|       
->02.45% (20,608B) 0x10AC08: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x10A9DB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int*> >::allocate(std::allocator<int*>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x10A566: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_map(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:614)
|     ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x10A81A: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_reallocate_map(unsigned long, bool) (deque.tcc:929)
|     | ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x10A36D: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_reserve_map_at_back(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:2116)
|     |   ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x109D34: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:470)
|     |     ->02.45% (20,608B) 0x109875: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |       ->02.43% (20,464B) 0x109499: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_stack.h:219)
|     |       | ->02.43% (20,464B) 0x10912E: Stack::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:19)
|     |       |   ->02.43% (20,464B) 0x108F11: main (mem_eater.cpp:55)
|     |       |     
|     |       ->00.02% (144B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     |       
|     ->00.00% (0B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->00.02% (176B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 41    230,069,860          857,944          846,128        11,816            0
 42    235,254,410          875,624          863,536        12,088            0
 43    240,656,059          892,784          880,432        12,352            0
 44    246,176,028          911,504          898,864        12,640            0
 45    251,968,045          931,264          918,320        12,944            0
 46    258,089,356          952,584          939,312        13,272            0
98.61% (939,312B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->88.79% (845,824B) 0x10AB96: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->88.79% (845,824B) 0x10A919: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->88.79% (845,824B) 0x10A398: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_node() (stl_deque.h:600)
|     ->88.74% (845,312B) 0x109D4C: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:471)
|     | ->88.74% (845,312B) 0x109875: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |   ->88.47% (842,752B) 0x109499: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_stack.h:219)
|     |   | ->88.47% (842,752B) 0x10912E: Stack::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:19)
|     |   |   ->88.47% (842,752B) 0x108F11: main (mem_eater.cpp:55)
|     |   |     
|     |   ->00.27% (2,560B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     |   
|     ->00.05% (512B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->07.63% (72,704B) 0x4EC16EE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
| ->07.63% (72,704B) 0x400F448: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|   ->07.63% (72,704B) 0x400F559: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|     ->07.63% (72,704B) 0x4000B88: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|       
->02.16% (20,608B) 0x10AC08: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int*>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x10A9DB: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int*> >::allocate(std::allocator<int*>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x10A566: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_map(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:614)
|     ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x10A81A: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_reallocate_map(unsigned long, bool) (deque.tcc:929)
|     | ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x10A36D: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_reserve_map_at_back(unsigned long) (stl_deque.h:2116)
|     |   ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x109D34: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:470)
|     |     ->02.16% (20,608B) 0x109875: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |       ->02.15% (20,464B) 0x109499: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_stack.h:219)
|     |       | ->02.15% (20,464B) 0x10912E: Stack::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:19)
|     |       |   ->02.15% (20,464B) 0x108F11: main (mem_eater.cpp:55)
|     |       |     
|     |       ->00.02% (144B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     |       
|     ->00.00% (0B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->00.02% (176B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)

 .....
```

Из графика видно, что использование памяти для данного игрушечного примера постоянно растёт. А из последующего отчёта видно, что ко времени снимка `46` для хранения стека уже используется (845,824+20,608) байт, или же больше 90% всей кучи используемой программой, что указывает на очевидную ошибку. Интерпретация вывода не механическая и требует некоторых усилий и сноровки, но это помогает увидеть на что стоит обратить внимание.

Если поправить злосчастный комментарий, то получается практически чистый вывод с несколькими ложноположительными срабатываниями связанными с простым пиковым потреблением памяти:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            ./mem_eater
Massif arguments:   (none)
ms_print arguments: massif.out.29399
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    KB
77.60^                                #::     :                     :         
     |       :@:::::::::::::::::::::::#: :::::::::::::::::::::::@::::::::@::::
     | :::::::@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
     | :: :: :@::: ::: :: ::::: :::: :#: :: :::::::: :: :::::: :@::::::::@::::
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Mi
     0                                                                   319.7

Number of snapshots: 66
 Detailed snapshots: [7, 26 (peak), 50, 60]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0              0                0                0             0            0
  1      6,357,999           74,624           74,544            80            0
  2     11,037,520           74,104           74,032            72            0
  3     18,736,364           74,104           74,032            72            0
  4     23,440,137           74,104           74,032            72            0
  5     27,510,682           74,104           74,032            72            0
  6     33,147,787           75,664           75,568            96            0
  7     38,465,295           75,664           75,568            96            0
99.87% (75,568B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->96.09% (72,704B) 0x4EC16EE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
| ->96.09% (72,704B) 0x400F448: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|   ->96.09% (72,704B) 0x400F559: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|     ->96.09% (72,704B) 0x4000B88: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|       
->03.38% (2,560B) 0x10AC9E: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->03.38% (2,560B) 0x10AA21: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->03.38% (2,560B) 0x10A4A0: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_node() (stl_deque.h:600)
|     ->02.71% (2,048B) 0x109DD6: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:471)
|     | ->02.71% (2,048B) 0x1098A1: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |   ->02.03% (1,536B) 0x1095AF: std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_queue.h:243)
|     |   | ->02.03% (1,536B) 0x109232: Queue::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:35)
|     |   |   ->02.03% (1,536B) 0x108F5E: main (mem_eater.cpp:59)
|     |   |     
|     |   ->00.68% (512B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     |   
|     ->00.68% (512B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->00.40% (304B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  8     43,466,034           75,664           75,568            96            0
  9     50,687,976           75,744           75,648            96            0
 10     54,674,907           76,784           76,672           112            0
 11     61,489,426           76,784           76,672           112            0
 12     66,913,719           76,784           76,672           112            0
 13     73,503,124           76,784           76,672           112            0
 14     80,840,510           75,744           75,648            96            0
 15     85,776,021           75,744           75,648            96            0
 16     93,894,556           76,784           76,672           112            0
 17     98,955,219           76,264           76,160           104            0
 18    104,342,732           76,784           76,672           112            0
 19    109,566,108           75,744           75,648            96            0
 20    116,286,750           76,784           76,672           112            0
 21    124,342,177           76,784           76,672           112            0
 22    128,350,479           77,824           77,696           128            0
 23    133,653,415           76,264           76,160           104            0
 24    139,392,895           77,824           77,696           128            0
 25    144,750,550           78,864           78,720           144            0
 26    151,838,741           79,464           79,312           152            0
99.81% (79,312B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->91.49% (72,704B) 0x4EC16EE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
| ->91.49% (72,704B) 0x400F448: call_init.part.0 (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|   ->91.49% (72,704B) 0x400F559: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|     ->91.49% (72,704B) 0x4000B88: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.25.so)
|       
->07.73% (6,144B) 0x10AC9E: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
| ->07.73% (6,144B) 0x10AA21: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:436)
|   ->07.73% (6,144B) 0x10A4A0: std::_Deque_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate_node() (stl_deque.h:600)
|     ->07.09% (5,632B) 0x109DD6: void std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_push_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) (deque.tcc:471)
|     | ->07.09% (5,632B) 0x1098A1: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_deque.h:1527)
|     |   ->03.87% (3,072B) 0x1095AF: std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_queue.h:243)
|     |   | ->03.87% (3,072B) 0x109232: Queue::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:35)
|     |   |   ->03.87% (3,072B) 0x108F5E: main (mem_eater.cpp:59)
|     |   |     
|     |   ->03.22% (2,560B) 0x1094A9: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::push(int const&) (stl_stack.h:219)
|     |     ->03.22% (2,560B) 0x10912E: Stack::store(int) (mem_eater.cpp:19)
|     |       ->03.22% (2,560B) 0x108F11: main (mem_eater.cpp:55)
|     |         
|     ->00.64% (512B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
|     
->00.58% (464B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)

 .....

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 61    318,903,255           77,384           77,264           120            0
 62    322,953,503           77,384           77,264           120            0
 63    327,012,737           77,384           77,264           120            0
 64    331,088,164           76,864           76,752           112            0
 65    335,212,302           76,864           76,752           112            0
```

### Другие утилиты

Кроме `massif` в valgrind'е есть другая схожая утилита: [DHAT](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dh-manual.html) (exp-dhat). Она работает несколько на другом принципе: для каждой точки аллокации она собирает статистику по количеству аллокаций/деаллокаций, чтениям/записям, а также времени жизни аллокаций. Её также возможно использовать для неявных утечек, но ИМХО вывод оной интерпретировать сложнее и её лучше оставить для поиска более тонких ошибок/оптимизаций: поиска сохраняемых, но не читаемых данных, оптимизаций избыточной аллокации, поиск выделений слишком больших блоков итп.